# Evaluating the integral $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{dx}{x^4-2\cos(2\theta)x^2 +1}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, branch-cuts

The first part of this question required me to find out the zeroes of the denominator, and to treat the equation as that of a complex number, which allows us to write:
$$\frac{1}{z^4-2\cos(2\theta)z^2 +1}=\frac{1}{(z-e^{i\theta})(z+e^{i\theta})(z-e^{-i\theta})(z+e^{-i\theta})}$$
As far as I can understand these zeros have the effect of giving a circle of singularities in the complex plane with radius 1.

I assume to do the integral given in the question, I would have to do some kind of contour integration over the complex plane, but I am stumped as to which contour I should use to do this. I assume a branch cut will also be needed due to the transcendental nature of the zeroes in the denominator.

As always and help is appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For the contour, you can simply choose a semi-circle of radius $R>1$in the upper half plane, as usual oriented counter-clockwise. I don't think you need to consider any branch cuts. You'll have two singularities in your contour, one at $z=e^{i\theta}$, and the other at $z=-e^{-i\theta}$. The integral over the semi-circle will vanish as $R\to\infty$. The sum of your residues is
$$\frac{1}{2e^{i\theta}}\frac{1}{2i\sin\theta}\frac{1}{2\cos\theta}+\frac{1}{-2e^{-i\theta}}\frac{1}{-2i\sin\theta}\frac{1}{2\cos\theta} = \frac{1}{4i\sin\theta}.$$
Hence, multiplying by $i2\pi $, 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^4 - 2 \cos(2\theta)x^2+1}= \frac{\pi}{2\sin\theta}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I am still slightly confused though, as it seems as though $z=e^{i\theta}$ and $z=-e^{-i\theta}$ are loci in the complex plane as opposed to a fixed numbers. Also wouldn't the contour run through these singularities as opposed to enclosing them?

Comment: EDIT - sorry I just saw that you said a semicircle with radius > 1 - in that case the contour would enclose the singularities. I am still a bit of stuck on the first point though.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but the integrand is done for a fixed value of $\theta$ so that e.g. $\exp(i\theta)$ is just a complex number.

Comment: Shouldn't this be $\pi/(2\sin|\theta|)$? The integrand is strictly positive, so the integral can't be negative.

Comment: @eyeballfrog See [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3764767/85343).

Comment: This solution implicitly assumes that $0<\theta<\pi$, so yes, either state this as an assumption, or specify that the absolute value of your result is obtained.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\underline{\underline{\mbox{With}\ \theta \not\in \pi\mathbb{Z}}}}$:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffe]{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\dd x \over x^{4} - 2\cos\pars{2\theta}x^{2} + 1}} =
2\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x^{-2}\,\dd x \over x^{2} - 2\cos\pars{2\theta} + x^{-2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
2\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x^{-2}\,\dd x \over \pars{x - x^{-1}}^{2} +
2\bracks{1 -\cos\pars{2\theta}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x^{-2}\,\dd x \over \pars{x - x^{-1}}^{2} + 4\sin^{2}\pars{\theta}} +
\int_{\infty}^{0}
{-\,\dd x \over \pars{x^{-1} - x}^{2} + 4\sin^{2}\pars{\theta}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\pars{1 + x^{-2}}\,\dd x \over \pars{x - x^{-1}}^{2} + 4\sin^{2}\pars{\theta}} =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\dd x \over x^{2} + 4\sin^{2}\pars{\theta}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 4\sin^{2}\pars{\theta}}\,
2\verts{\sin\pars{\theta}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\dd x/\bracks{2\verts{\sin\pars{\theta}}} \over \braces{x/\bracks{2\verts{\sin\pars{\theta}}}}^{2} + 1}
\\[5mm] = &
{1 \over 2\verts{\sin\pars{\theta}}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\dd x \over x^{2} + 1} =
\bbx{\pi \over 2\verts{\sin\pars{\theta}}}\,,\qquad
\theta \not\in \pi\mathbb{Z}
\end{align}